# Limit 3 rows per user id

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that goes:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, messages.id, messages.name

FROM messages
INNER JOIN users on messages.user_id = users.id

WHERE users.active = true

ORDER BY users.id, messages.sent_at
```

What I want is for the query to return the first 3 rows for each `users.id`, is it possible?

I did not find any question similar to this one in stackoverflow or any other site. I appreciate any answer or helpful link. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` inside a subquery/derived table:

```
select users_id, users_name, messages_id, messages_name
from (
  SELECT users.id as users_id, users.name as users_name, messages.id as messages_id, messages.name as messages_name, messages.sent_at
    , row_number() over (partition by users.id order by messages.sent_at) as rn
  FROM messages
  INNER JOIN users on messages.user_id = users.id
  WHERE users.active = true
) as sub
where rn < 4
ORDER BY users_id, sent_at
```